# Android storage and detection trouble on PC

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have an Android 6.0 phone. Up until recently, I would plug in my phone to my laptop via USB cable and when drag photos/sync music to the micro SD card in the phone with no issues. The USB connection setting on the phone was set to MTP. Now, when I plug in the device, it will charge but nothing will show up. I can access internal storage by changing USB connection settings to PTP and access the microSD in a slower, more of a hassle kind of way by changing the setting to USB storage which has to be turned on/off and the phone has to read every file on the card again each time. I don't know why this happens now. Any help with accessing the SD card the way it used to be, while it's in the phone?

Comment: Try clearing cache and data for "media storage" and "external storage" from app manager, than reboot and wait up to 10 minutes after boot and connect to PC and see if it's allright now.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing snapPea on your laptop.

snapPea lets you manage your android device from your system. Hope that solves your problem.